# Autocomplete Arrow Key Scroll

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, ajax

I am making a Ajax driven live search . But now I want to click the dropdown list to fill the html textbox. How can I modify my codes to include a function where the user can scroll through the results list using the up/down arrow keys. Here is the JavaScript code.

```js
<script type="text/javascript">
    function fill(Value) {
      $('#name').val(Value);
      $('#display').hide();
    }

    $(document).ready(function() {
      $("#name").keyup(function() {
        var name = $('#name').val();
        if (name == "") {
          $("#display").html("");
        } else {
          $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "ajax.php",
            data: "name=" + name,
            success: function(html) {
              $("#display").html(html).show();
            }
          });
        }
      });
    });
```

and here is the code in `ajax.php` page

```
if(isset($_POST['name'])) { 
$name=trim($_POST['name']);
$query=mysqli_query($con,"SELECT * FROM mobile WHERE name LIKE '%$name%' LIMIT 0,5"); 
echo "<ul>"; 
    while($query2=mysqli_fetch_array($query)) 
    { ?>
          <div class="ajaxcontainer">
            <li onclick='fill("<?php echo $query2[' name ']; ?>")'>
              <a href="preview.php?id=<?php  echo $query2['name']; ?>">
                <div class="ajaximage">
                  <img src="<?php echo $query2['photo'];?>">
                </div>
                <div class="ajaxh1">
                  <h1><?php  echo $query2['name']; ?></h1>
                </div>
              </a>
            </li>
          </div>
          <?php } } ?>
```

Comment: Warning: this script has a SQL injection vulnerability.

Answer (score 0):

good news.. after working 3 hours.. i got the solution to ur problem. Checkout the solution. let me know if you have any problems in this solution.I

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.2.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<style type="text/css">
ul{
    position: absolute;
    top: 5px;
    left: 36px;
    list-style: none;
}
li{
  border: 1px solid grey;
  width: 202px;
  margin: 0px;
}
input{
  width:200px;
}
</style>
<script>

function showHint(str){
  if(str=="" || !str){
    $("ul").empty();
    return;
  }
    $.ajax({
          type: "GET",
          url: "gethint.php",
          data: "q="+str,
          success: function(html) {
            var names = html.split(",");
            var listItems ="";
            var dropDown =$("#dropDown");
            dropDown.innerHTML="";
            $("ul").empty();
            names.forEach(name =>{
              var li = document.createElement("li");
              li.appendChild(document.createTextNode(name));
              dropDown.append(li);
              $("li").click(function(){
                $("#txt1").val($(this).text());

              });
            });

          }
    });
  }
</script>
<h3>Start typing a name in the input field below:</h3>

<form action=""> 
  <div style="position:relative">
    First name: <input type="text" id="txt1" onkeyup="showHint(this.value)">
    <ul id="dropDown"></ul>
  </div>
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

This is my php file.

```
<?php
require("connection.php");

$sql ="SELECT name FROM users";
$a=array();
// OR $a=[];
$result=$conn->query($sql);
if($result->num_rows > 0){
    while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()){
        $a[]=$row["name"];
        //echo $row["name"];
    }
}
else{
    echo "No data to generate suggestions";
}
// get the q parameter from URL
$q = $_REQUEST["q"];

$hint = "";

// lookup all hints from array if $q is different from "" 
if ($q !== "") {
    $q = strtolower($q);
    $len=strlen($q);
    foreach($a as $name) {
        if (stristr($q, substr($name, 0, $len))) {
            if ($hint === "") {
                $hint = $name;
            } else {
                $hint .= ", $name";
            }
        }
    }
}
?>
```

Comment: sorry it does not work. I copy the html codes into a sample.html file and php codes to gethint.php and make connection to my database and try to fetch mobile name . Nothing comes . I just want the code for implementing up and down arrow key selection action to my working project. So I want to know instead of onclick event what we want to do.