# Ajax driven live search with arrow key scroll

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I am making a Ajax driven live search . But now I want to click the dropdown list (Here the #display div tag act as that) to fill the html textbox with id=name. How can I modify my codes to include a function where the user can scroll through the results list using the up/down arrow keys. Here is the JavaScript code.

Here is javascript code in index.php file

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    function fill(Value)
    {
    $('#name').val(Value);
    $('#display').hide();
    }

    $(document).ready(function(){
    $("#name").keyup(function() {
    var name = $('#name').val();
    if(name=="")
    {
    $("#display").html("");
    }
    else
    {
    $.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: "ajax.php",
    data: "name="+ name ,
    success: function(html){
    $("#display").html(html).show();
    }
    });
    }
    });
    });
    </script>

                        <form  method="POST" action="search.php" >
                            <input type="text" value="Enter Product Name Here" onfocus="this.value = '';" onblur="if (this.value == '') {this.value = 'Enter Product Name Here';}" name="name" id="name" required/>
                            <input type="submit" value="SEARCH"/>                        

                        </form>
                        <div class="dis">
                        <div id="displayl"></div>
 <div id="display"></div>
 </div>
                    </div>
```

and here is the code in ajax.php page

```
if(isset($_POST['name'])) 
    { 
    $name=trim($_POST['name']); 
    $query=mysqli_query($con,"SELECT * FROM mobile WHERE name LIKE '%$name%' LIMIT 0,5"); 
    echo "<ul>"; 
    while($query2=mysqli_fetch_array($query)) 
    { ?>
          <div class="ajaxcontainer">
            <li onclick='fill("<?php echo $query2[' name ']; ?>")'>
              <a href="preview.php?id=<?php  echo $query2['name']; ?>">
                <div class="ajaximage">
                  <img src="<?php echo $query2['photo'];?>">
                </div>
                <div class="ajaxh1">
                  <h1><?php  echo $query2['name']; ?></h1>
                </div>
              </a>
            </li>
          </div>
          <?php } } ?>
```

Comment: You don't have a standard dropdown control (tag select with option), but probably you have a JQuery plugin that turns your "ajaxcontainer" in a dropdown, if is true, please complete your code with these details.

Comment: This appears to be a [copy and paste of this question](http://stackoverflow.com/q/35244169/472495). Strangely, the OP on the other question, @Geordy, has edited this question too. What's going on?